# Why aren't my if statements going through?

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script

I am creating a bash script that is suppose to copy all files in `~/Development/` to another computer on my network. I have enabled it to mount the computer if it is not there, but my real problem is creating folders.

I want to save the files in `/Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups/Development/`, therefore I run some if statements to check if they exist.

```
#! /bin/bash


echo "Starting Backup of Development Files"
echo
say "Starting Backup of Development Files"



if [ -d "/Volumes/Users/Public/" ]; then
    # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists.
echo "Location is there..."
echo

    # Start 
echo "Copying Files"
echo

if [ ! -d "/Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups/Development" ] ; then
  echo "/Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups/Development did not exist."
  say "Location did not exist, creating it."
  cd /Volumes/Users/Public/
  if [ ! -d "/Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups"]; then
  say "InfiniteBackups did not exist, creating it…"
  mkdir InfiniteBackups

  fi

  if [! -d "/Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups/Development"]; then
  cd InfiniteBackups
  mkdir Development
  fi


fi

cp -v -rip ~/Desktop/ /Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups/Development
echo "Files have finished transferring"
say "Files have finished transferring"

fi
```

It will say /Volumes/Users/Public/ exists, and it will say /Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups/Development does not exist. It then checks to see if /Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups/ exists, which it shouldn't. Then it is suppose to make the directory. However, it instead acts like the volume did exist even though it clearly doesn't.

Why doesn't it work. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `mkdir -p` and `cp -r`?

Comment: What does mkdir -p do. I am using -r for cp.

Comment: You check if some directory exist, if not, create it. `mkdir -p` create path, with all required parent dirs. It do not consider mistake directory existance, so you can just `mkdir -p /Volumes/Users/Public/InfiniteBackups` without conditional.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. That is quite useful. Oh, but what argument do I use so that cp will automatically overwrite my previous files? After the first backup I have to say yes to each overwrite.

Comment: Look in manual. There is a lot there. To force overwrite, use `-f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a space between " and ]. You are missing that in two places. The whole test returns a non-zero number all the time because it's giving an error.

I tested my theory on Linux, it should be the same for OS X...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I haven't really used bash scripts that often. I wasn't aware that white spaces did anything. Well, it's working now.

Comment: Your image seems to be broken

Comment: I can see it. Here's the location http://i.stack.imgur.com/bMwYp.png